# Are we going to sail past 2000 unanswered questions?

Tags: discussion

Sorry if I've abused the Meta board somewhat. I was just browsing unanswered today and noted that we're up to **1,934** questions with no upvoted or accepted answers, with **1,417** questions with no answers.

My OCD is tingling....

This topic has been discussed at some length here : [What can we do to ensure people accept answers?](https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99/what-can-we-do-to-ensure-people-accept-answers) however apart from my reply its gone stale, with one extra post in 2014 and nothing else since end of 2012.

I just wondered if there's been any progress on this topic? If the 'powers that be' are listening and if there's any thoughts on some of the ideas and feature requests in the previously linked topic?

I realise in the grand scheme of things EE is small fry, Magento SE has twice as many unanswered, Drupal & WP SE's have 15k, 14k respectively and SE proper has over 2 million!! However I am keen on the idea we can all work smart and keep the EE SE tidy, lead the way by example...

Upvotes and answer points on offer for any reasonable updates on this (i.e. not the first person to say "Yes, yes we are") LOL